# How do I add a SharePoint web service to a sub site?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am currently trying to add a Web Service which will allow me to find if the person who is editing a form is part of the Owners group.  It seemed like I found a solution with the GetCommonMemberships data connection, but the webservice only points to the main server, and will only pull the groups from there. How do I make it so that I can point my web service at a subsite instead of the mainserver?

Comment: basically is there a way to do this but without code: http://lrathi.blogspot.com/2008/06/error-while-trying-to-access-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 1):

The web services are available everywhere regardless of where you're at.  You'll want to look at the Users and Groups web service, `http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx`.  There are a few good oerations available like GetUserCollection and GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser.

Comment: right, but I want to access the groups for one specific subsite, not the groups for the main server.

Comment: example, something like this (not working): http://mainsite/subsite/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx

Comment: That should work, it's exactly how I configure datasources in SharePoint Designer in subsites for various uses.

Comment: oh wait, im opening a data connection in infopath, how would I configure the datasources in SharePoint designer?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that is the proper structure.  As a test, I just opened InfoPath 2010, went to the data tab and told it to connect to a web service.  I entered a site collection and a subsite in my 2007 SP farm, http://my.spsite.com/sites/sitecoll/subsiet/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx?WSDL and it showed me all the operations available.

Comment: ok now im curious if im doing something completely wrong, or if youre misunderstanding me. so for a test, make a drop-down list menu. have that list pull in values from a data connection which receives data from a web service like: http://ServerName/sites/subsite/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx. (choose  GetCommonMemberships). Now when I publish the form, the drop down menu does populate. But with information from the mainserver and not the subsite. how would i get the groups like "Members" or "Owners" of the subsite to show up?

Answer (score 1):

All of the core web services are available to all sites and webs throughout the environment. You'd reference the web service directly to the site you want to access, ie: http://intranet/departments/deptA/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx.

Whether you're using jQuery or not, there's an excellent compilation of web service documentation on the SPServices site, [http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices&referringTitle=Documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: I get an error saying: The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
<detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The parameter loginName cannot be empty or bigger than 251 characters.</errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x80131600</errorcode></detail>

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your script, not the web service itself. How are you calling it? JavaScript? Did you provide it a value for loginName?

Comment: Nope, I'm opening a data connection in infopath and recieving data using the link format "http://intranet/departments/deptA/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx."

Comment: You will still need to provide at least the required parameters for the web service; simply pointing to the web service won't do much (if anything).

Comment: you have to set up the data connection as query, and then set the loginName field of the secondary datasource to the loginName of the user you want (i.e. InfoPath's userName() function) and then query the data connection